# Why extra spacing in table cell when it has 2 href elements

Tags: html, css, html-table

Picture's worth a thousand words. Note the space between the last line and the rest.

[image]

Here's the code.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<style type="text/css">
td a {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
font-size:11px;
font-family: Arial, 
}
</style>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="120px"><a href="#" target="__blank">Now is the time for all good men to come to the aide of their country said the quick brown fox to the lazy cow.</a> <a href="#" target="__blank">Moo</a></td>
    </tr>
</body>
</html>
```

If I take out the second a tag and include the Moo text within the first a tag, the spacing goes away.  What's going on here?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t6zyz/   What space?  What browser/platform? Looks firefox/ubuntu-ish.

Comment: I dont see where your td is ended properly

Comment: the <a> tag could be having some kind of line-height to it... check your css

Comment: @williamcarswell The `td` element in HTML does not require a closing tag ([see the HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6)). The `table` element does though!

Answer (score 2):

Right now you are missing closing `td` and `table` tags.  They could be the issue.

It works fine for me with the closing tags:

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bmNRq/

Comment: The `td` element in HTML does not require a closing tag (see the [HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6)). The `table` element does though!  Omitting these tags in your jsFiddle doesn't reproduce the error for me.  This looks like a browser-specific quirk.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you have sent the font size within the `a` tag to a smaller-than-default size.  This means that the space character between the two `a` tags is being rendered in the standard font size (e.g. 14px) and thus is making the line it is on higher than the others.

Try changing your CSS to:

```
<style type="text/css">
td {
    font-size:11px;
    font-family: Arial, 
}

td a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I agree with this answer.  The one character of spacing between the a tags could be rendered with a taller font size.  I'd like to know what browser version is being used.  In FF7 and Chrome 14, I'm not getting that space but I'm getting the line height as equal to the TD font size: http://jsfiddle.net/t6zyz/4/  The correct approach would be to apply the font-size and family to "td" and the color and decoration to "td a".

Comment: Agreed. I can't reproduce the error either, so I think this must be a browser-specific quirk.  I've added your CSS suggestion to my answer, for clarity.  Thanks.

Comment: I get this with Chrome (14.0.835.202) and FF(3.6.23 - Ubuntu).  I tried body{..same as a}, so the space should be the same font size as the ref tags, and the results are the same.

Comment: You're on Ubuntu?  I should have realized from the icons.  That may explain why no one can reproduce it.  I would recommend using Firebug or Chrome dev tools to see exactly what font styles are being applied to the TD versus the A.  There are some historical issues where body styles don't apply to TD or two different fonts will be different heights with the same font-height.  It may even be a problem with a library your browsers depend on.  (Do they both still use Cairo for font rendering?)

Comment: I have reproduced the error by saving the original html to a local file and viewing it in Chromium 14.0.835.202 and Firefox 7.0.1 (both on Arch Linux).  (Incidentally, the error occurs regardless of whether there is a closing `</table>` tag, so this is not the problem).  However, changing the CSS to what is in my answer above solves the issue.  It is indeed the font size of the space character between the `<a>` elements and you need to set the font size for the whole `<td>` to solve it.